# cast is null only in visual studio debugger on some computer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, casting

I have a really strange problem:

```
object aObject = LoadObject();
MessageBox.show(aObject.GetType().Name) //box shows "Action"
Action aAction = aObject as Action;
```

if i do that in debugging in code, aAction is null. 
if i make a breakpoint somewhere and write (aObject as Action).Id in direct input field of visual studio i get correct value (nothing is null).

if i run the exe from bin/debug folder, it works... the cast is done and aAction is not null.

What the hell is wrong here?

Comment: if you're using the debugger, you can see what the underlying type really is

Comment: are you using multiple threads? because this is usually a reason for such differences between debugging or not. Anyway, without knowing what `LoadObject` does there isn't much I can do - does aObject have value after being loaded?

Comment: What is the GetType().FullName? Is your Action something different than the one your returned object has? There are bugs in the debugger expression evaluation engine which was changed in VS2015 again which has now other bugs. You should not trust 100% the values you see in the debugger.

Comment: There is no namespace problem. For testing this i used the complete namespace in front of the type. The object is definitly the type i want to cast. The code runs if I start the exe. The cast don't work only in debugging.

if i use Action aAction = aObject as Action; aAction is null. if I use Action aAction = (Action)aObject; the cast returns an Exception.

Again: the code works if I start the exe, and the cast works in direct console of visual studio if I set a breakpoint. Only in code in debugging it is null.
And only on one machine! We tested there with VS2013 and VS2015, same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that your `Action` is in a different namespace.

For example, maybe `LoadObject` returns a `MyApp.Action`, where your `aObject as Action` is attempting to cast as `System.Action`.

If so, the easiest fix is to say `aObject as MyApp.Action`. Or avoid naming a class `Action` in the first place, to avoid conflicting with stuff in the `System` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

There is no namespace problem. For testing this i used the complete namespace in front of the type.

The object is definitly the type i want to cast. The code runs if I start the exe. The cast don't work only in debugging.

if i use 
Action aAction = aObject as Action;
aAction is null.
if I use 
Action aAction = (Action)aObject;
the cast returns an Exception.

Again:
the code works if I start the exe, and the cast works in direct console of visual studio if I set a breakpoint. Only in code in debugging it is null.

And only on one machine! We tested there with VS2013 and VS2015, same problem.